# I would like to redirect the domain name to the server subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect the domain name to the server subdirectory by using apache rewrite rules .How could I change the .htaccess file?

www.a.com bound to /a

www.b.com bound to /b

I could not change httpd-vhosts.conf because some Cross-domain issues.

The /d has a .htaccess file ,i would caught the 404 error if i deleted it,or I would caught the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS .

The .htaccess file:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is: (save as `.htaccess` on your website's root)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /full/path/to/document/root/%1/$1 [END]
```

Website root, is the `DocumentRoot` defined on your apache2/vHost config.
You said you want www.a.com redirects to `/a`, `DocumentRoot` is the full system path to URL path `/`

This will work on Apache 2.4, NOT 2.2.

Reply to the first comment:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(a|b|c).com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /full/path/to/document/root/d/$1 [END]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /full/path/to/document/root/%1/$1 [END]
```

Comment: Thank you . And if I want a.b.c redirects to /d ,how to edit the rules?

Comment: @autumnfall Appended to my answer. Wait, your a.b.c is supposed to be a domain name? then  `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a.b.c$`

Comment: The /d has a .htaccess file ,i would caught the 404 error if i deleted it,or I would caught the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS .